# Submit form over a select element in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So in my file i have this working example of submitting a form and initiating a controller action. And in this form there is a functioning select element and it works as expected, the controller is able to retrieve the value in the select element.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertEntry", "Modeliai"))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pavadinimas" name="Pavadinimas">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="fk_MARKEid">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Markes)
                {
                    <option data-tokens="@item.pavadinimas" data-content="@item.pavadinimas">@item.id</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
    </div>
}
```

But when i try to add select element in the table row, controller somehow doesn't catch the value of the select element.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateEntry", "Modeliai"))
{
    <td>
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.id" />
         <input type="text" name="pavadinimas" class="form-control" value="@item.pavadinimas" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="fk_MARKEid">
            @{
                var ignore = Model.Markes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == item.fk_MARKEid);
            }

            @foreach (var x in Model.Markes)
            {
                if (ignore?.id == x.id)
                {
                    <option data-tokens="@ignore?.pavadinimas" data-content="@ignore?.pavadinimas" selected="selected">@ignore?.id</option>
                }

                <option data-tokens="@x.pavadinimas" data-content="@x.pavadinimas">@x.id</option>
            }

            </select>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px">
        <button class="close" type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" style="font-size: smaller"></i>
        </button>
    </td>
}
```

Yes i tried checking if select element names and model names match.

Any help regarding making the second form work or explanation why does this happen would be appreciated

Comment: The only change you made is to switch from `div`s to a `table` and it does not work now ? Are you getting the value of `pavadinimas` ? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Yeah you are correct the only thing i changed was that, and yes i am getting the value of `pavadinimas` so it is partially working

Comment: I solved the issue by adding a hidden input

Answer (score 0):

The better way to use select in ASP.Net MVC is to use @Html.DropDownListFor with SelectList.

## Example: View

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.YourModel, new SelectList(ViewBag.customValue, "Text", "Value"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

## Example: Controller

```
        List<SelectListItem> listForSelect = new List<SelectListItem>();

        listForSelect.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Your text", Value = "Your value" });

        ViewBag.customValue = listForSelect;
```

Comment: The actual reason i didn't want to use `Html.DropDownListFor` because i can't make it seem to work with bootstrap `selectpicker` class and `data-live-search` option